# What auto keyword does under the hood when used with function pointers?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr, auto, pointer-to-member

While experimenting with `auto` and function pointers I notice a strange behavior

```
class Test
{
public:
    void Func(){}
};

static constexpr const auto member_ptr1{ &Test::Func }; // compile fine
static constexpr const void(Test::*member_ptr2)(void) { &Test::Func }; // ERROR : cannot convert from void(Test::*)(void) to const void(Test::* const)(void)
```

I understand that, in the case of `member_ptr2`, the compiler complain about not finding a function with the signature `const void Func()` , but it should trigger the same error for `member_ptr1`.

So what does the compiler do under the hood with `member_ptr2` ?

Bonus question : what does `const` means right after `Test::*` ? I notice that in the compiler output.

Second bonus question : When using function pointers is there any difference between `constexpr const auto member_ptr1{...}` and `constexpr auto member_ptr1{...}` ?

Comment: please one question per question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
static constexpr const auto member_ptr1{ &Test::Func };
```

declares a constant pointer to a member function. That is the pointer itself that is constant.

This record is equivalent to

```
static constexpr void(Test::* const member_ptr2)(void) { &Test::Func };
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

class Test
{
public:
    void Func(){}
};

static constexpr const auto member_ptr1{ &Test::Func }; // compile fine
static constexpr void(Test::* const member_ptr2)(void) { &Test::Func };

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << std::is_same<decltype( member_ptr1 ), decltype( member_ptr2 )>::value
              << '\n';
              
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
true
```

And here is another simplified demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x = 10;
    const auto p = &x;
    
    *p = 20;
    
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 20
```

That is the pointer `p` has the type `int * const` not the type `const int *`.

The type in place of the placeholder `auto` at first is deduced from the used initializer and then the qualifier const is applied to the deduced type.